# ffmpeg starts too slow when using ip camera (the same as using OpenCV)

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg

Here is my code:

```
ffmpeg -i http://192.168.0.101:8889/video?dummy=param.mjpeg out.mjpg
```

When I run this command, it will immediately print below:

```
ffmpeg version N-70223-g7296716 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      54. 19.100 / 54. 19.100
  libavcodec     56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
  libavformat    56. 23.105 / 56. 23.105
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 11.101 /  5. 11.101
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
```

However, **it takes almost twenty seconds before showing next line**, and it prints **this warning**:

```
[mjpeg @ 0000000002c4fec0] Format mjpeg detected only with low score of 25, misdetection possible!
```

Then it prints this:

```
Input #0, mjpeg, from 'http://192.168.0.101:8889/video?dummy=param.mjpeg':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 25 tbc
Output #0, mjpeg, to 'a.mjpg':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.23.105
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc), 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=2-31,
200 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.26.100 mjpeg
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> mjpeg (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  195 fps=0.0 q=24.8 size=    1022kB time=00:00:07.80 bitrate=1073.6kbits/
frame=  199 fps=185 q=24.8 size=    1043kB time=00:00:07.96 bitrate=1073.6kbits/
frame=  203 fps=125 q=24.8 size=    1064kB time=00:00:08.12 bitrate=1073.6kbits/
```

What's worse, when I am using `OpenCV`, the `open` of the `VideoCapture` also takes the same long time!

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(){
    cout<<"Start"<<endl;
    VideoCapture cap("http://192.168.0.101:8889/video?dummy=param.mjpg");
    cout<<"End"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

20s after printing "start", it prints "end".

I am using `ffmpeg` on win7 64 bit downloaded from [here](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/).

Any idea will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with:

`ffmpeg -f mjpeg -i http://192.168.0.101:8889/video?dummy=param.mjpeg out.mjpg`

Other options if that doesn't work:

> It may take too long because MJPEG streams don't include timestamps,
> and by default they are generated by ffmpeg like there's 25 FPS.
>
> Try ffmpeg -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 -i ​http://...
>
> Try ffmpeg -f mjpeg -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 -i ​http://...
>
> Try ffmpeg -f mjpeg -i ​http://...
>
> Try also -probesize 32 -analyzeduration 0
>
> or something like that to reduce probing period.

Source: http://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/2343

Comment: By the way, only `ffmpeg -f mjpeg -i http://... out.mjpg` is available, but `ffmpeg -i http://... -f MPEG out.mjpg` is **unavailable**!

Comment: I re-read your comment. You always need to specify the input type `ffmpeg -f mjpeg -i http://... -f mpeg out.mpeg`. You need two `-f`, one for input and one for output